# Handle exceptions within a returned promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I know this is not the most beautiful code, but due to legacy issues, I need to stick to this workflow.

The problem is that I am not able to bubble up any exceptions that might occur in the heart of the returned promise.

The code is designed that both the `reject` and `resolve` return valid data. So, if you change the `const CONDITION` to `0.4`, we will be getting a rejection. If the value of `const CONDITION` stays at `0.6`, we will be getting a resolution. This works so far.

However, in cases where we have structural failures, such as in the example below where we try to pass a wrong variable name into the rejection:

```
let reasoxxxx = '__FAILED__';
reject({error: reason, data: output});
```

I am not able to invoke a `throw` to bubble up the error. For that reason, I am getting the usual ugly message and I cannot bubble up a proper exception:

```
Exchange request was rejected due to error(s).
(node:224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: reason is not defined
(node:224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any ideas? The code snipped should work.

```js
function fakeFetch() {
  // Promisify the request.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Emulate an asynchroneous fetch.
    setTimeout(() => {
      let result = 0.4; // Change to 0.4 to trigger a failed fetch.
      if (result < 0.5) {;
        reject('__FAIL__');
      } else {
        resolve({name: 'apple', price: '1234.12', time: 1549926859970});
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function sendExchangeRequest(id, pair, symbols, callback)
{
  let err, result
  await fakeFetch().then((output) => { result = output }).catch((error) => {err = error})
  if(err){
    result = 'None'
  }else{
    err = 'None'
  }
  callback(err, result)
}

async function fetchExchangeData(id, pair, symbols) {
    // Promisify the request.
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                // Send the request.
                sendExchangeRequest(id, pair, symbols, ((err, output) => {
                    try{
                        if(err){
                            // Soft Failure
                            console.log('Exchange request was rejected due to error(s).');
                            reject({error: err, data: output});
                        }else{
                            // Success
                            console.log('Exchange request was successful.');
                            resolve({error: err, data: output});
                        }
                    } catch(error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                }));
            } catch(error) {
                console.log('---\n', error, '\n---');
                throw error;
            }
        });
    } catch(error) {
        // Bubble up the error?
        console.log('+++\n', error, '\n+++');
        throw error;
    }
}

(async () => {
  await fetchExchangeData('myid', 'MYPAIR', 'mySymbol')
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((failure) => console.log(failure))
})();
```

--- EDIT (01) ---

I have updated my example snipped to include a fake API call. I hope this makes my question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not understanding the concept of async functions. Your first `try/catch` in `fetchExchangeData` do essentially nothing, and there is nothing async in it. The try/catch inside the initial promise, is also almost useless, as I'm sure most/all issues with `sendExchangeRequest` will likely be dealt with the error handler function `(err)`. As for the try/catch blocks, you shouldn't throw errors inside the promise, you should instead reject the error (Which will bubble it up). Only try/catch if you're in an async function, and NOT using callbacks.

```
function fetchExchangeData(id, pair, symbols) {
    // Promisify the request.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            // Send the request.
            sendExchangeRequest(id, pair, symbols, ((err, output) => {
                try{
                    if(err){
                        // Soft Failure
                        console.log('Exchange request was rejected due to error(s).');
                        let reason = '__FAILED__';
                        reject({error: reason, data: output});
                    }else{
                        // Success
                        console.log('Exchange request was successful.');
                        resolve({error: '__NONE__', data: output});
                    }
                } catch(error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            }));
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('---\n', error, '\n---');
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should consider posting your `sendExchangeRequest`, and move away from callbacks entirely if at all possible.

Comment: `sendExchangeRequest` is already in the snippet. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, FrankerZ, the first `try {}` is there to catch any issues that might occur before we reach the promise. I am aware that there is no code in that section yet, but there might be some in the future. Sorry, if it was misleading.

Comment: If `sendExchangeRequest` throws synchronously, it's violating the implicit contract of the Node.js-style callback API. I'm very much inclined to think that your outer `try...catch` is useless too.

Comment: I have added a comment, the `sendExchangeRequest` is performing an async API call. Let me add a sensible place holder.

Comment: I have added a fake API call that should make the example code a bit more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to add you in discord but, I don't think it is working.

Comment: Thanks to @FrankerZ, the lesson here is that a promise rejection is capable bubbling up an error. For the full solution please see this: https://repl.it/@cryptoeraser/TestSolution